Jacobi iteration matrix
I was given a question in which I needed to prove that given a system of equations, $Ax=b$ such that $A$ is a real, invertible square matrix - prove that if $A$ is symmetric and the spectral radius of the Jacobi iteration matrix (which is $-D^{-1}(L+U)$, or at least that's how they defined it in my class) is $0$ then the algorithm will converge to the solution within 1 iteration.
I just can't figure out why that would necessarily be true, if we want the algorithm to end within 1 iteration, shouldn't the iteration matrix be the zero matrix? since ($e_1 = Te_0$), and I can find plenty of examples in which A would be symmetric and the iteration matrix would not be $0$, so is there a mistake in the question in your opinion, or am I just misunderstanding something here?
just to clarify if anyone is not familiar with this method :
$D$ is the diagonal of $A$, $L$ is the lower triangular part of $A$ without the diagonal, and $U$ is the upper triangular part of $A$ without the diagonal.

Since the text is considering the Jacobi method, they must necessarily assume that the diagonal $D$ of $A$ is nonsingular. Let $$G = -D^{-1} (L + U)$$ denote the iteration matrix. By assumption, all eigenvalues of $G$ are zero. However, $G$ is similar to $$F = -D^{-\frac{1}{2}} ( L + U) D^{-{\frac{1}{2}}},$$ because $$G = D^{-\frac{1}{2}} F D^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$ Therefore the eigenvalues of $F$ are all zero. The symmetry of $A$ implies the symmetry of $F$. It follows that $F$ can be diagonalized and since all eigenvalues are zero, we now know that $F$ is the zero matrix. It follows that $G$ is the zero matrix.
Remark: I fell into the trap and quietly assumed that the diagonal entries of $A$ are positive. This is not necessarily so.

that is so simple yet brilliant, thank you very much!

@JohannCarlFriedrichGauß You are very welcome.
